# $\tilde{P}(A) = \int_AZ(\omega) dP(\omega)$ is $\tilde{P}(A) = Z(\omega)P(A)$ when $A$ is mall

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $P$ and $\tilde{P}$ two probability measures related by :

$$\tilde{P}(A) = \int_AZ(\omega) dP(\omega)$$

with $Z$ the Radon Nikodym derivative.

Now (This is what I don't understand) if the set $A$ is small and contains $\omega$ then :

$$\tilde{P}(A) = Z(\omega)P(A)$$

Can anyone help understand how do we get to this last equation? How do we prove it? How can I see it intuitively? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let this be a discrete probability space, say, let $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$ and let the two probability measures be $P_a, P_b, P_c$ and $\tilde P_a, \tilde P_b, \tilde P_c$ such that all these numbers are positive. And define $$Z(\omega)=\frac{\tilde P_{\omega}}{P_{\omega}},\ \ \omega\in\Omega.$$

Whit this

$$\tilde P(A)=\int_{A}Z(\omega)\ dP=\sum_{\omega\in A}\frac{\tilde P_{\omega}}{P_{\omega}}P_{\omega},\ A\subset \Omega$$
for all $A\subset \Omega.$ So, $Z$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\tilde P$ with respect to $P$.

Comment: I don't see the answer to my question. How could someone go from equation 1 to equation 2 (in my post), given that $A$ is small ?

Comment: I gave an example in the case of which the smalles $A $ is a single $\omege $. I hoped that this would enlighten the core problem.